# Get-ChildItem can't find dir when script run with -File instead of -Command

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, get-childitem

I had to change my script to use -File instead of -Command and it used to find the dir with GetChildItem but now it's not finding it.  The script is called from an old old perl script, and this is what it looks like there:

```
my $resultPS = `"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe" -NoProfile -noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File "\\\\wserverp01\\support\\Retailer_SN\\MoveSNToSprdsht_1.0.ps1" -outFilePathExcel_pl "$service_report_xls" -out_pth "$retailer_blob_scan_dir"`;
```

I have logged and verified the variables contain what they should in the perl script.  I used to use -Command without the passed parameters but now have the requirement of passing the xls and dir as parameters so changed it to -File.

In the powershell script, I am logging my parameters and they look good except for the trailing / is removed for the $retailer_blob_scan_dir, whereas it used to be in the string defined in the ps script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param( [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$outFilePathExcel_pl,  [Parameter()][string]$out_pth="\\wserverp01\support\Retailer_SN\OutputSprdsht\")

Start-Transcript -path '\\wserverp01\support\Retailer_SN\Logs\MoveSNToSprdsht.log' 

Write-Host "new tab will go to:$($outFilePathExcel_pl)" #need to use below instead of $outFilePathExcel############################
Write-Host "Will get blob scan files from:$($out_pth)"

#make sure params are valid paths
if('' -eq $out_pth)
{
    Write-Host "out_pth was blank so setting it"
    $out_pth = "\\wserverp01\support\Retailer_SN\OutputSprdsht\"
}

if('' -eq $outFilePathExcel_pl)
{
    Write-Host "outFilePathExcel_pl was blank so setting it"
    $outFilePathExcel_pl = "\\WserverP01\support\path_Summary\Retailer_ServicePropertiesReport.xlsx"
}

[System.String] $excel_File_from = ""

############## hours - 72 hours is ok for now so we don't cut it too close for file timestamp for blob scan..blob scan run on weekend, use Monday:
Get-ChildItem $out_pth | Foreach-Object {$lastupdatetime=$_.LastWriteTime;$nowtime = get-date; if (($nowtime - $lastupdatetime).totalhours -le 72) {write-host "here2";$excel_File_from=$_.Name;write-host $_.name}}
```

Since the file in out_pth was created Sunday, I edited it and so the date is today now in explorer. So it's within 72 hours.  The error in Get-ChildItem is

Get-ChildItem: \wserverp01\support\Retailer_SN\MoveSNToSprdsht_1.0.ps1:63
Line |
63 |  Get-ChildItem $out_pth | Foreach-Object {$lastupdatetime=$_.LastWrite …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot find path '\WserverP01\support\Retailer_SN\OutputSprdsht"' because it does not exist.

It used to find this dir with Get-ChildItem and the only thing I can think of is the trailing slash, or call with File instead of Command so I can use the parameters when I run it. They also changed it so they want to generate the file in out_pth over the weekend, so I've changed my time used in Get-ChildItem to 72 hours from 12 hours. Permissions in the system scheduler during run of the perl script has not changed. Any info on what this issue could be and how to fix it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem is the double quotes around the $retailer_blob_scan_dir, in the perl call to MoveSNToSprdsht powershell script. I see double quotes when I print it out in the powershell script too.

When I removed the double quotes in perl, the prolbem went away and the dir is found:

```
my $resultPS =  "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe" -NoProfile -noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File "\\\\wserverp01\\support\\Retailer_SN\\MoveSNToSprdsht_1.0.ps1" -outFilePathExcel_pl $service_report_xls -out_pth $cvs_blob_scan_dir`;
```